# Expecting a List[Future], what if there is a failed Future?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have list of IPs like this

```
val ips = List("ip1", "ip2", "ip3")
```

I use that list to do http get requests via my wrapper get method, and my wrapper get method will throw `BadRequestException` if the response status is `400`. I understand if I get all success say `200` since myWrapper returns `Future[WSResponse]`, in good case my end result will be `List[Future[WSResponse]]`

Example snippet

```
def myresponses(ips:List[String]) = {
    ips.map(ip=>myWrapper(ip))
}
```

My confusion and question is that since `myWrapper` can throw an exception in case of status `404`, will other guys still execute? In short in bad case say where one request gives `404` and say the remaining all give `200`, is it going to be the case that I will have `List[WSResponse]` and for one of the elements it will be an exception? Or it will not be the case and if one Future has failed, the others might not even execute?

Answer (score 0):

They will all execute. If there is an exception, that element will be a failed future. It will still have the *type* `Future[Response]`, but if you try to `Await.result` on it, an exception will be thrown. If you try to further transform (`map`, `flatMap`, etc.) such failed `Future`, nothing will happen (the transformation will never be executed). 
You can handle those exceptions with `.recover` or `.recoverWith` (they are like `.map` and `flatMap`, but will only invoke the transformation if the future has failed), or report/clean up it with `.onFailure` (there is also `.onSuccess` and `.onComplete`, that handles both cases).

There is a good tutorial on dealing with scala futures here:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html